# In crypto.constant_time_compare, why the time taken is independent of the number of characters that match?

Tags: python, django

Why does the comment in the code say that *'The time taken is independent of the number of characters that match'*?

In my opinion, the time taken should depend on the number of chars.

The code is copied from Django, [crypto.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/crypto.py#L85)

```
def constant_time_compare(val1, val2):
    """
    Returns True if the two strings are equal, False otherwise.

    The time taken is independent of the number of characters that match.

    For the sake of simplicity, this function executes in constant time only
    when the two strings have the same length. It short-circuits when they
    have different lengths. Since Django only uses it to compare hashes of
    known expected length, this is acceptable.
    """
    if len(val1) != len(val2):
        return False
    result = 0
    if six.PY3 and isinstance(val1, bytes) and isinstance(val2, bytes):
        for x, y in zip(val1, val2):
            result |= x ^ y
    else:
        for x, y in zip(val1, val2):
            result |= ord(x) ^ ord(y)
    return result == 0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's independent of the number of characters *that match*, not the number of characters in total. It is, as you note, linear in the number of characters in the string.

It's intended to avoid timing exploits that rely on comparison algorithms that bail as soon as they reach a non-matching character.